# What schematic symbol is this switch with an arc?

Tags: switches, symbol, schematic

I've referenced many symbol sheets with no avail.

What would JP5 'AutoON' be here? I assume it's a switch that is default on, but the symbol is foreign to me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be it can be a symbol of protective relay

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The symbol and 'JP' label suggest that it is a jumper used to bypass the switch.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 2-pin jumper on a 5-way pin header. Image source: [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9044).*

Comment: Another use for the jumper pins could also be to install an alternative remote switch, either for integration into a larger system or for automation of the power-on function by a micro or logic controller, etc.

Answer (score 8):

The JP5 is most likely just a standard jumper block, maybe a standard 2.54mm/0.1" pin header with two pins, allowing the user to use pushbutton manually when jumper is removed or short out the pushbutton permanently by mounting the jumper block.

Answer (score 3):

It's a circuit breaker symbol used incorrectly to indicate a jumper block. Given that this symbol is quite universal, its misuse is misleading - the schematic's author might as well used no symbol besides the two terminals, and with the JP reference designator it'd have been obvious still what it is.